# Is this mix of the essential and the non-essential phrases correct?

Tags: punctuation

> We left some flowers **on the table**.

The bold part is the non-essential.

> We left the flowers **which were red**, onto the table.

The bold part is the essential.Is comma necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't

> We left the flowers **onto** the table.

because *onto* implies motion, *left* does not. *on* is OK.

No comma used here; you are only separating a prepositional phrase.